# Fast search within text files in windows

Tags: windows, desktop-search, file-search

Is there a program for windows that would do a great job of searching within files?

I have a folder that I constantly need to search in for certain text, It would be nice to have a program that caches the files and searches through them quickly, and keeps its cache updated.

I spend a lot of time searching with netbeans, notepad++ and etc, the problem is this is a folder on a network, so it opens every file each time and searches.

Comment: "so it opens every file each time and searches." - This will be true for any search tool that is not caching a copy of the files anyway. The tool **must** open the file to search it.

Comment: I suppose the user means, not opening the file every time a search is invoked. Otherwise I would have recommended `grep` ;)

Comment: Yeah I prefer something that stores a cache, but other than that, grep so far has had the best performance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Windows Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Search) it is available for Win XP up to Win 7. A more complete list of desktop search engines can be found at [wikipedias site about desktop search engines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_search_engines#Desktop_search_engines)

**Edit:** A good (probably the best) tool to find stuff in text files (w/o caches) is [grep](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm). (Refer to my comment to the question)

Answer (score 8):

I always use `findstr`, which is roughtly comparable to grep, but windows native.

Example:

```
findstr /s /i /m "MyClass" *.cpp
```

This will search recursively (`/s`) within the current folder. It will look into every file whose name matches `*.cpp` for the string `MyClass`.

`/i` ignores case

`/m` only print file names of matching files

You can open command line windows anywhere in windows by doing a right click while holding down shift anywhere on the free space in any folder. (Don't right click on files)

`findstr` will be noticably faster the second time you search within the same directory since windows caches opened files.

Comment: this is the best solution to avoid any complexity

Answer (score 1):

Use glimpse / glimpseindex, as far as we are talking about ASCII textfiles here.
It creates a very small index, since it does **not** store the line of occurence but only the fact that it occurs - so, a grep will be done, but **only** in the files actually **containing** the word, which is fast.
Use 
  glimpseindex
to index your harddrive,
and use 
   glimpse  to search. the output is similar to grep.
Easily adaptabe to emacs.

Comment: This is **not** an answer to the original question. Your solution is for Unix **not** Windows

Comment: These days Microsoft supports running Linux tools on Windows with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux and there are Windows builds too: https://github.com/glimpse-editor/Glimpse/releases/download/v0.2.0/glimpse-0.2.0-i686.msi

Answer (score 0):

Use the `find` command.
For example to find `yourstring` in all `*.txt` files:

```
C:\YourFolder\>find "yourstring" *.txt
```

If you're on a network, just map the drive to `Z:\` for example, and run `find` from that drive.